# Dynamically search database and show results using Javascript and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I want to search a database for a clientName and dynamically show the results while the user is typing so they can select a User. It is now my understanding that this cannot be done without using javascript.

So if the user is typing "Al" then reults of clients called "Allan, Alison, Ali..." etc would show in a dropdownlist like display under it.
At the moment the user is entering the Clients name into a Textbox.

I know that creating the DropDownList should be done something like this:

```
private void InitializeNameDropDown(DataTable dtTable)
{
    string ClientName = Clienttb.Text;
    MySqlDataReader Reader = MySQLQuery(ClientName);
    int nTotalRecords = dtTable.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < nTotalRecords; i++)
    {
        NameDropDown.Items.Add(dtTable.Rows[i]["Client"].ToString());
    }
}
```

MySQLQuery() just checks that the client exists within the database.
But I don't know how to dynamically interact with the database to return the results as the user is typing.

Any Help will be appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because if a user has Javascript disabled (NoScript etc...) then it would not work. I also do not have much experience using Javascript.

Comment: Not possible without JavaScript (well, XMLHttpRequest). If user has JavaScript disabled, then they get the inferior experience of typing it in, clicking enter then waiting for the whole page to load. If they have JavaScript enabled, they get the happy path of results returning as they type

Comment: Hmm..Ok then, I shall modify my question to use javascript. Is it easy enough to do in Javascript instead?

Comment: If a user has JS disabled they loose this type of functionality. Personally, I don't think its worth bothering to support people who insist on turning it off.

Comment: ASP.NET requires javascript. Take a look at your postback controls.

Comment: @BNL: I agree, to a certain extent. It is not worth taking away a feature because it will not work for them. If the page still functions for them (albeit synchronously), then it is fine.

Comment: The jQuery UI Autocomplete widget is quite popular for this kind of thing http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/.

Comment: @Mac - Depends what you mean by easy! Take a look at http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ and http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to hook into the keyup event on the text box and fire an XmlHttpRequest from that event - if you're using jQuery it's pretty simple:

```
$('#mytextbox').keyup(function() { $.ajax(blah blah) });
```

Alternatively, as Dennis says, just use the auto-complete plugin - it's very simple and works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without JS, hang event on text change on TextBox (OnTextChanged), and in there update DDL ( dont forget to set AutoPostBack=true ).
But it can easily make user wait ( "freeze page" ), or even rollback what he wrote if you are using Ajax.NET

I strongly recommend using JS rather then this ( use JS and WCF/ashx/regular WS, any of these will do ) due to performance gain and much better possibilities of customization.
ASP anyway generates a load of JS for "ASP controls".

This can be applied for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Cross_Domain_Call.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As for the client side try jquery and jqueryui's autocomplete, it's just a suggestion, jquery has a nice ajax call and it's really simple to use, and for the jqueryui autocomplete, you just pass it keywords and it will create a list right under the input box.

http://jquery.com/

http://jqueryui.com/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that might get you going.

It uses the **[jquery](http://jquery.com/)** Javascript library. It assumes you're getting the full HTML of the results list that you want to display to the user. You'll need more Javascript to dynamically show/hide the box that contains the list. You'll also need a server-side script that gets a collection of search results based on some search text. That script should be located at the URL defined in the **#searchPartialUrl** tag (which can be hidden). The search text should be in an input called **#searchText**.

I like this method because you can maintain your JS code in a separate file and reuse it. Your server just needs to create HTML views that have all the async target information in regular HTML tags.

I also implemented a delay between checking key-events so that you're not constantly sending requests to your server. (I got this method from another answer on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find it now. I'll give credit when I do.)

```
// This function is used to delay the async request of search results
// so we're not constantly sending requests.
var mydelay = (function() {
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

var asyncSearchForm = function(onSuccess) {

    var keyupWrapper = function(keyCode) {

        // if this key was an arrow key, then
        // ignore the press
        for (var i = 37; i <= 40; i++)
            if (keyCode == i)
            return;

        // get all the search info from the form
        var searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        var searchPartialUrl = $('#searchPartialUrl').val();

        // make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: searchPartialUrl,
            data: {
                searchText: searchText
            },
            dataType: "html",

            // on success, the entire results content should be replaced
            // by the results returned
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#searchResults').html(data);
                onSuccess();
            },

            // on error, replace the results with an error message
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#searchResults').html('<p>An error occurred while getting the search results.</p>');
            }
        });
    };

    onSuccess = (typeof (onSuccess) == 'undefined') ? function() { } : onSuccess;

    // On each key-up event, we'll search for the given input. This event
    // will only get triggered according to the delay given, so it isn't
    // called constantly (which wouldn't be a good idea).
    $('#searchText').keyup(function(e) {

        // delay between each event
        mydelay(function() {

            // call key up
            keyupWrapper(e.keyCode);

        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Update:

You said you're using C#. If you're using MVC, you'll need an action in your controller to be a target for your async request. Here's an example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSearchResults(string searchText)
{
    // Here, you should query your database for results based
    // on the given search text. Then, you can create a view
    // using those results and send it back to the client.
    var model = GetSearchResultsModel(searchText);

    return View(model);
}
```